# create multidimentional array from singledimentional array

Tags: c#, arrays, parsing

Ok, so i have this string array that looks something like this:

```
myArray[0] = "a0,b0,c0,d0"
myArray[1] = "a1,b1,c1,d1"
myArray[2] = "a2,b2,c2,d2"
myArray[3] = "a3,b3,c3,d3"
etc...
```

I want to create a multidimentional array that uses the first part of each element as "key". In short:

```
myMultiArray:
x/y|  0   |  1   |  2   |  3   |
------------------------
 0 | "a0" | "a1" | "a2" | "a3" |
 1 | "b0" | "b1" | "b2" | "b3" |
 2 | "c0" | "c1" | "c2" | "c3" |
 3 | "d0" | "d1" | "d2" | "d3" |
```

this is what I've got:

```
 private String[,] resultsParser(String[] inputArray)
    {
        String[] splittedString = null;
        String[,] outputString = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length; i++ )
        {
            splitString = inputArray[i].Split(',');
            for (int j = 0; j < outputArray.GetLength(0); j++)
            {
                if (splitString[0] == outputArray[j, 0])
                {
                    for (int k = 1; k < splitString.Length; k++)
                    {
                        outputArray[j, k] = splitString[k];
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < splitString.Length; k++)
            {
                outputArray[outputArray.GetLength(0), k] = splitString[k];
            }
        }
        return outputArray;
    }
```

- Problem1: it doesn't work
- Problem2: the code is fugly

Is there some easy way of doing this?

Comment: "it doesn't work" doesn't describe what happens. It looks to me like it won't even *compile*, which really doesn't help.

Comment: The solution is actually pretty simple, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me you need to separate this into two stages:

- Determining the size
- Splitting each row and copying the results

Each of these is reasonably simple, but you'll find the code much simpler if you separate them. Something like:

```
public static string[,] SplitResults(string[] input)
{
    int columns = input[0].Split(',').Length;
    string[,] output = new string[input.Length, columns];

    for (int row = 0; row < input.Length; row++)
    {
        string[] split = input[row].Split(',');
        for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
        {
            output[row, column] = split[column];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

However, you should add validation:

- `input` should not be null
- `input` should not be empty
- Every row should be the same size

Note that the code above splits the first row twice (once to find the size, and once to populate the data). While you *could* fix that to be more efficient, it would make the code more ugly - I wouldn't do it unless you really found it to be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to create a multidimensional array, `string[,]`? Because it's pretty easy to create a jagged array, `string[][]`:

```
string[][] newArray = new string[inputArray.Count][];
for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.Count; ++i)
{
    newArray[i] = inputArray[i].Split(',');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private String[,] resultsParser(params String[] input){
    String[,] array = new String[input.Length, input[0].length];//x is the total elements, y is the elements in each array
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < input.Length ; i++ ){
        array[i] = input[i];
    }
    return array;
}
```

this is not tested but I believe it should work